# change the default text in selectbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have select box with the id '**edit-field-service-line-tid**' which is having the default text '**-Any-**' for default value.

This select field is generated by [drupal](https://www.drupal.org/). So I want to change the text '-Any-' to 'Success Stories' in jquery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-field-service-line-tid" name="field_service_line_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
  <option value="1">Retail</option>
  <option value="2">Big Data</option>
  <option value="3">Cloud</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't have any option called `Success Stories`. do you want to change the option itself?

Comment: Does it always comes first? I mean is always the first option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
$('#edit-field-service-line-tid option:eq(0)').text('Success Stories');
});
```

```html
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-field-service-line-tid" name="field_service_line_tid" class="form-select">
<option value="All" selected="selected">--All--</option>
<option value="1">Retail</option><option value="2">Big Data</option>
<option value="3">Cloud</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Question is asking to change that dynamically using jquery, not in the code itself

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
$('#edit-field-service-line-tid option[value="All"]').text('Success Stories');
```

It should work.

Comment: can you give some fiddle example

Comment: Thanks @ABCatella :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the first element of option by id and change its text.

BY ID:

```
$($("#edit-field-service-line-tid option")[0]).text('Success Stories')
```

Comment: OP is not asking to change the first element.

Answer (score 0):

just change the value of the select box as you do for the textbox like

```
$("#selectboxid).val('selectvalue');
```

Comment: This will just select another item from the select and not change the text as the op wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
$('select option:contains("- Any -")').text('Success Stories');
});
```